# 3 plus symbols between two variables (like a+++b) in C

Tags: c, syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=8,b=9,c;
    c=a+++b;
    printf("%d%d%d\n",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

The program above outputs `a=9 b=9` and `c=17`.  In `a+++b` why is the compiler takes `a++` and then adds with `b`.  Why is it not taking `a +` and 
`++b`?  Is there a specific name for this `a+++b`.  Please help me to understand.

Comment: I'm sure there was an even more general question about this... with multiple + but it's very difficult to search for `++++`...

Comment: I'm not sure why you've got the bit about sequence points in the question: "There should not be more than one modification of a variable before the sequence point.If it happens then the behaiour is undefined.". Which variable do you think is modified more than once before a sequence point here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I like the explanation from [Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298):

> The ANSI standard specifies a convention that has come to be known as
> the  **maximal munch strategy**. Maximal munch says that if there's more
> than one possibility for the  next token, the compiler will prefer to
> bite off the one involving the longest sequence of  characters. So the
> example will be parsed
>
> ```
> c = a++ + b;
> ```

Comment: Never knew this, nice answer.

Comment: @cnicutar:Good explanantion.Thanks for making me to understand.

Comment: +1. This multiple '+'s thing makes for ugly code though. I would be much happier seeing c = (a++) + b

Comment: @cnicutar: Does it hold good for C++ as well?

Comment: @Als I believe it does. For instance I remember g++ complaining about `vector<vector<int>>`. Then again, I don't know much C++.

Comment: The maximal much rule can cause some surprising results. `a+++++b` is tokenized as `a ++ ++ + b`, which is a syntax error. If not for the rule, it *could* be tokenized as `a ++ + ++ b`, which is legal and meaningful. The point of the rule is to guarantee that all compilers will do the same thing, and if you really want to write `a ++ + ++ b`, adding white space will make it unambiguous to the compiler *and* clear to any human readers.

Answer (score 5):

Read [Maximum Munch Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)

> > "maximal munch" or "longest match" is the principle that when creating some construct, as much of the available input as possible should be consumed.

---

Every compiler has a tokenizer, which is a component that parses a source file into distinct tokens (keywords, operators, identifiers etc.). One of the tokenizer's rules is called "maximal munch", which says that the tokenizer should keep reading characters from the source file until adding one more character causes the current token to stop making sense

Comment: :thanks for the link.I will go through it.

Answer (score -1):

Order of operations in C dictate that unary operations have higher precedence than binary operations.

You could use a + (++b) if you wanted b to be incremented first.