# Why does "case::LABEL:" compile in g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I was surprised to learn that g++ (4.9) was compiling this (while gcc would not):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum
{
    ONE   = 1,
    TWO   = 2,
    THREE = 3
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sw = 2;

    switch (sw)
    {
    case::ONE:
    {
        printf("1\n");
        break;
    }

    case::TWO:
    {
        printf("2\n");
        break;
    }

    case::THREE:
    {
        printf("3\n");
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        printf("default\n");
    }
    }
}
```

How is the g++ preprocessor able to separate the "case" from the "::ONE:"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is the g++ preprocessor able to separate the "case" from the "::ONE:"?

It's not the preprocessor, but simply the compiler, that interprets `::` to refer to the global namespace.

The case labels will be parsed as

```
case :: THREE :
```

and that's perfectly OK, as your `enum` values appear in the global namespace (`::`).

Comment: Once Cecilio fixes the 'root' namespace, your answer will become a duplicate ;)

Comment: I meant to say "parser", not "preprocessor".

Comment: @John You have to be precise about that, the preprocessor is a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the preprocessor. The C compiler (its tokenizer) sees that as:

`case :: ONE`

which is ok in c++. The :: operator means the root namespace. C has no such thing.

Comment: There is no root namespace, it is a global namespace.

Comment: "C has no such thing": thus it's the C++ compiler, not the C compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple enum, not a scoped enum (see: `enum class`). Plain enums are in the root scope, hence you can write `::ONE`.

With scoped enums, you can do the following:

```
enum class Scoped { FIRST, LAST = 9};
//...
case Scoped::FIRST : //...
```

The tokenizer in g++ (as this is a C++ feature) can resolve even if you don't leave whitespaces between the `case` keyword and the enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

During the [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) phase of the compilation process, the stream of characters in the program file is converted to tokens. One of the popular algorithms used here is [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) in which the longest matching legal token is considered as the intended token. In this example, it breaks the `case::ONE:` into `case`, `::`, `ONE` and `:`.

There are also some disadvantages: `x = y/*z` is an error since `/*` is the longest matching legal token, while the user probably wanted to say `x = y / *z`. You can find many such curious examples, couple of them are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233317/3-plus-symbols-between-two-variables-like-ab-in-c).